# why did not work delete button in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using this delete button to delete task in table

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete pull-right"
data-action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}"
data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
</button>
```

this is delete controller

```
public function deleteOneProjectTask($projectId, $taskId)
    {
        DB::table('tasks')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('id', $taskId)
            ->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.show')->with('info', 'Task deleted successfully');
    }
```

and routes

```
Route::delete('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTasksController@deleteOneProjectTask',
]);
```

but when I click delete button it is not delete task. but when I refresh it it will delete. how can fix this?